# jQuery animate div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have this jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/uM68j/

When I click on one of the links from that, the bar should slide to the top, but what it is doing is just jumping to the top, not animating. How can I get it to animate?

I think it is actually the CSS that is causing this:

JS:

```
$(".nav-bar div, .nav-bar div a").click(function () {
    $(".nav-bar").animate({
        top: "0"
    }, "fast");
    return false;
});
```

CSS:

```
.nav-bar {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ededed;
}
```

Comment: I know the answer provided below is good but out of curiosity, which browser have you tested. It's animating up in FF mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have'nt set a `top` value in CSS, so you're animating from `auto` to `0`, which does'nt work. You did however set a `bottom` value, so animate that instead:

```
$(".nav-bar div, .nav-bar div a").click(function () {
    $(".nav-bar").animate({
        bottom: $(window).height() - 100
    }, "fast");
    return false;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uM68j/1/)